# Running nohup without it sending a message

Tags: linux, bash

Hi i have a bash script and run a proces like this

```
nohup $proces &
```

When i do that the scipt sends a massage like

```
nohup: appending..
```

Is there a way to prevent the massage output? Or is there an alternative command that does the same and there is no massage send out?

Comment: You can just redirect the output from nohup to `/dev/null` (`nohup yourcommand > /dev/null 2>&1`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Discard all output: `nohup $process > /dev/null 2>&1 &`